# how to get all email from user input with coma and remove the comma and shot it in array

Tags: php, email

i would like to send email to multiple user from an input of the email from text box, and separate each email with comma, now my issue is i was unable to separate the email and shot it in array

```
<?php $recipients = array("youladdress@yourdomain.com","youladdress@yourdomain.com","youladdress@yourdomain.com");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email_to = implode(',', $recipients); 
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; 
    $thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; 
    foreach($recipients as $email_to)
    { mail($email_to, $email_subject, $thankyou);}
}
?>
```

the above code  send the email out as expected

```
<?php $recipients = array($_POST['email']);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email_to = implode(',', $recipients); 
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; 
    $thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; 
    foreach($recipients as $email_to)
    { mail($email_to, $email_subject, $thankyou);}
}
?>
```

is there any mistake because i didnt get it as expected

Comment: You are converting the array into string and then inside the `foreach` overriding it as the value for the array and sending emails one by one.

Answer (score 0):

remove `array` from assigning result. Otherwise it will be `multidimentional array`

```
<?php $recipients = $_POST['email']; //<----remove array
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email_to = implode(',', $recipients); 
    $email_subject = "Contact Form Message"; 
    $thankyou = "thankyou.htm"; 
    foreach($recipients as $email_to)
    { mail($email_to, $email_subject, $thankyou);}
}
?>
```